# Time-complexity of while loop in big-O

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having trouble indicating the time complexity of a simple while loop in terms of input n.

The while loop executes as long as i < n and i is incremented by one more than the number of previous iteration. For example, in the 2nd iteration, i is incremented by 1, in the 3rd iteration, by 2, and so on... Essentially, the loop executes "final value of t" times.

```
func(n):
    i = 1
    t = 1

    while (i < n):
        i = i + t
        t = t + 1
```

My question is, how can I indicate the time complexity of this algorithm in big-O notation?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF which should give you a hint at how you can calculate how many times the loop will run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Essentially, the loop executes "final value of t" times.

You're halfway there. You know that the loop executes t times, now you just need to solve for t.

Your loop will end when the sum of 1..t is greater than or equal to n. By solving the [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation), we can express this as

```
t*(t-1)/2 >= n
```

By rearranging the equation to show t in terms of n, we get

```
t >= 1/2 (1 - sqrt(1 + 8 n))
```

But, we also know that the loop ends at the lowest (first) value of t that satisfies the inequality. Let us call that value tn. If tn is the first value that satisfies the inequality, then tn-1 is the last value that satisfies the opposite inequality.

```
tn - 1 <= 1/2 (1 - sqrt(1 + 8 n))
```

From this, we know that t is bounded above and below by some function of sqrt(n) and some constants. So then t is Θ(sqrt(n)), which means t is also O(sqrt(n)).